# How do I add a an image which is in CSS to a span in html

Tags: html, css

Below is the html code:

```
 <div class="whyimgbx">
       <span class="partnerHospitals">
       </span>
 </div>
```

instead of the above, if I give the image url directly into span it's working fine:

```
<span><img src="assets/images/1.png" alt=""></span>
```

But when give the class name in span its not working

Below is the CSS:

```
.partnerHospitals {
   background-image: url(assets/images/1.png)!important;
}
```

I am not getting `partnerHospitals` image in the span tag. Please, can someone suggest why this is not working?

Comment: What does "I am not getting partnerHospitals image in the span tag." mean? Like when you look at it in the inspector?

Comment: The image is not getting rendered in the browser. I am not able to see the background url  in inspect as well.

Comment: you have to add `width` `height` or some `padding` to div, make sure your image url is right !

Comment: Yeah its working fine now. After adding height and width

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because span has no content, it has no size. You need to add size to the element:

```
.partnerHospitals {
   background-image: url(assets/images/1.png);
   display: block; // or inline-block to preserve spans behaviour
   width: 150px;
   height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: I have added width and height, But when i inspect this class itself is not shown. But when i directly use img src like <span><img src="assets/images/1.png" alt=""></span> its working fine.

Comment: did you add the display: block?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.partnerHospitals {
   background-image: url(assets/images/1.png);
   width: yourWidth;
   height: yourHeight;
   display:block
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many things that could cause this.

1. the span `partnerHospitals` doesn't have a width/height set. So it doesn't occupy any space.
2. the url for the image is not correct.
3. others :)

For 1. Check answer below

```css
.partnerHospitals {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/50x50");
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="whyimgbx">
           <span class="partnerHospitals">
           </span>
 </div>
```